# C - Structures as parameters

Tags: c

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int i;
};

void* new(struct anyStruct) //I want to be able to pass any structure here
{
    void* p = malloc(sizeof(anyStruct));
    return p;
}

struct MyStruct* m = new(MyStruct);
```

Is it possible to do something like this in C? 
And what is m called? Object?

Comment: Maybe you want a macro: `#define NEW(t) (malloc(sizeof(t)))`

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, it is possible in C, but not as a function.   Use a macro

```
#define NEW(x) (malloc(sizeof(x)))

struct MyStruct *m = NEW(MyStruct);
```

Note, however, that this is a very bad idea, since macros do not honour scope, so the usage is error prone.

Actually, you don't need a macro at all.   All you need to do is

```
struct MyStruct *m = malloc(sizeof(*m));
```

The caveat on this is that it does not work outside a function (e.g. at file scope).  But neither does the macro approach.

Remember, if you use `malloc()`, it is your responsibility to call `free()`.

Comment: I want to do some other stuff as well, that is why I want it in a function

Comment: Then it's not possible.  Function overloading (two or more user-written functions with the same name but different argument types) are a feature of C++, not C.

Comment: Is it possible to do more than malloc in the #define statement?

Comment: Not if you want the macro to expand to multiple statements and have a return value.  It's one or the other - they are mutually exclusive with the standard C preprocessor.    Also #define is a preprocessor directive, not a statement  (a statement is something else).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't pass "any" type by value, and you can't pass type names. Type names (and types) are compile-time concepts, they don't exist at runtime which is why everything has to be statically expressed.

The best way is often to use the idiom:

```
struct MyStruct *m = malloc(sizeof *m);
```

This uses `sizeof` to compute the required size, which of course relies on `m` having the proper type.

Comment: Should be noted that although this idiom attempts to generalize the operation as much as possible, there are situations where it's not applicable. E.g., a buffer of contiguous memory with header of specific type, followed by raw data.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have something like you described. However, you can add a wrapper on top of `malloc()` to perform some other sanity checking. Something like

```
void* new(size_t size) //collect the size directly
{
    void* p = malloc(size);
    if (p)
        return p;
    else
    {
        printf("malloc() failed !!!\n");
        exit (-1);
    }
}

struct MyStruct* m = new(sizeof *m);
```